# PyEnchant: spellchecking block of text with a personal word list

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant

So PyEnchant allows you to define a personal word list of correctly spelled words in addition to a language dictionary:

```
d2 = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US","mywords.txt")
```

However, the resulting `d2` checker is of class `Dict`, which can only be used to check a single word, e.g.:

```
>>> d.check("Hello")
True
```

The `SpellChecker` class allows spellchecking of a block of text. However, I can't seem to find out how to specify a personal word list as with `Dict`. Is this not a supported feature? I'd like to spellcheck a block of text against en_US plus my personal word list. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *specify a personal word list*?

Comment: @aj8uppal: meaning the file `mywords.txt` holds a list of words that I want spellchecked. More info here: http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#personal-word-lists

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first argument of the SpellChecker initializer can be both the name of a language or an enchant dictionary:

```
from enchant import DictWithPWL
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker

my_dict = DictWithPWL("en_US", "mywords.txt")
my_checker = SpellChecker(my_dict)

my_checker.set_text("This is sme sample txt with erors.")
for error in my_checker:
    print "ERROR:", error.word
```

The documentation isn't clear about this, but [the code is available](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant/blob/master/enchant/checker/__init__.py#L132) :)