# PyEnchant - correct mistakes with words from personal word list

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant

I am using PyEnchant to spellcheck a large German text with lots of medical terms. To avoid that the medical terms are wrongly marked as errors, I am using `enchant.DictWithPWL` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898355/pyenchant-spellchecking-block-of-text-with-a-personal-word-list). My personal word list (PWL) contains many medical terms.

However, a lot of technical terms have spelling mistakes so they will still be detected as errors. Regrettably, pyenchant does not seem to use the words from my personal word list to correct the terms. As a result my text contains many wrong words after the spell check.

Is there a way to ensure that PyEnchant uses words from my personal word list to correct spelling mistakes? Adding the words manually using "store_replacement" won't work because the text is far too big.